# Does CountVectorizer().fit_transform() preserve order of input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, countvectorizer

I'm wondering if, when I use `CountVectorizer().fit_transform()`, the output preserves the order of the input.

My input is a list of documents. I know that the output matches the input in terms of the length, but I'm not sure if they are ordered the same way.

I understand that I might not be explaining it very well, so here's an example.

Say if I have:

```
input = ["<text_1>", "<text_2>", "<text_3>"]
a = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(input)
```

Will the indexes correspond as though order is preserved?

For example, in:

```
  (0, 33)   1
...
  (0, 42)   8
...
  (385, 58) 1
  (385, 51) 6
```

Is `(0, 33) 1` eqivalent to `input[0]`, or `(385, 58) 1` to `input[365]` ?

Comment: when you say "order" do you mean order of documents of order of words?

Comment: Order of documents. I've tried to clarify in my main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the row order is preserved. This must be true for all scikit-learn transformation methods, because a common workflow is to split your data into a feature matrix `X` and a target vector `y`, where each row of the matrix corresponds to one element of the vector. When you transform `X`, you must still be able to train the model on the transformed `X` paired with `y`, so the order must be preserved.